# How to determine if a giving start and end time has expire in php

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

Please i want to create a php code to check if time has expired or still active based on the start date and end time that users specified.
Below is the database structure and sample php code which i tried.

game_config

```
game_id | start_date | start_t | start_h | end_time | end_h | status  
--------|------------|---------|---------|----------|-------|---------
100     | 03/26/2018 |  10:45  | PM      |   12:30  |  AM   | 0 
101     | 03/27/2018 |  09:23  | AM      |   11:10  |  AM   | 0
```

**Php code sample**

```
<?php
    $conf_execution_date = date('m/d/Y'); /*Current date*/
    $conf_execution_meridiem = date('A'); /*Current meridiem*/
    $conf_execution_timer = date('h:m'); /*Current time*/
    $conf_execution_proccess = false;    /*Proceed or not*/

    $conf_handler = $appconn->prepare("
        SELECT * FROM game_config WHERE game_id = :game_id AND start_date = :start_dateAND start_t = :start_t AND status = 0 LIMIT 1
    ");

    $conf_handler->bindParam(":game_id", 100);
    $conf_handler->bindParam(":start_date", $conf_execution_date);
    $conf_handler->bindParam(":start_t", $conf_execution_meridiem); 
    $conf_handler->execute();
    $appconf = $conf_handler->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    if($appconf){
        $config_start_time = strtotime($appconf->start_t);
        $config_end_time = strtotime($appconf->end_time);
        $current_time = strtotime($conf_execution_timer);

        if($appconf->start_h == $conf_execution_meridiem){ /*AM-PM*/
            if($config_start_time >= $current_time){ /*Check if the start time is now o still active*/
                $conf_execution_proccess = true;
            }
        }

        if($appconf->end_h == $conf_execution_meridiem){ /*AM-PM*/
            if($config_end_time >= $current_time){ /*Check if the time has ended*/
                $conf_execution_proccess = false;
            }
        }

        if($conf_execution_proccess == true){
            echo 'YES THE GAME IS STILL ACTIVE';
        }else{
            echo "NO GAME HAS ENDED";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: You'd make your life a lot easier if you combined `start_date`, `start_t` and `start_h` into a single `TIMESTAMP` column; and likewise for the end time.

Comment: @eggyal please can you post an answer so i can understand what you really mean? Or if any thing that i can adjust in database to make it work fine i will be glad to do that

Comment: I mean, you're investing a lot of energy in reinventing the wheel.  Every MySQL column is defined to hold data of a particular type—it's not clear to me what type your existing columns are, but it's entirely possible you're simply using strings?  You could instead use datatypes that are specifically designed to hold temporal values—see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html

Comment: @eggyal even i change the datatype it won't sold the issue, i need to compare the time in DB and CURRENT time i think

Comment: Yes, but you can do that very easily—even within the database, e.g. `SELECT ... WHERE NOW() > endTimestamp ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `start_date` column is type `VARCHAR()`:

Assuming your `end_time` is always later in the day than your `start_time`:

You can use this sort of query to get a starting and ending `DATETIME` value for each row of your table. It glues together the date, the time, and the AM/PM fields and converts them to `DATETIME`. (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2d84ea/1/0)

```
SELECT game_id, 
       STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(start_date,'-',start_t,start_h), '%m/%d/%Y-%h:%i%p') start_ts,
       STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(start_date,'-',end_time,end_h), '%m/%d/%Y-%h:%i%p') end_ts,
       status    
  FROM game_config
```

Then you can compare those `start_ts` and `end_ts` values to `NOW()` by appending this line to your query

Then you can fill out your query with the criteria you need, giving this query.

```
SELECT game_id, 
       STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(start_date,'-',start_t,start_h), '%m/%d/%Y-%h:%i%p') start_ts,
       STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(start_date,'-',end_time,end_h), '%m/%d/%Y-%h:%i%p') end_ts,
       status    
  FROM game_config
 WHERE game_id = : gameid AND status = 0
HAVING start_ts <= NOW() and NOW() < end_ts
 LIMIT 1
```

But, your start and end times sometimes span midnight, which means your end_ts needs to be on the next day.  That makes your date-checking logic quite a bit trickier. You'll have to do some sort of conditional expression in which you do `+ INTERVAL 1 DAY` to your `end_ts` if it is before your `start_ts`.

You will be much better off  (@eggyal pointed this out in his comment) if you put the following columns in your table.

```
game_id   int
start_ts  timestamp of start
end_ts    timestamp of end
status    int
```

Then you don't have to worry about all the stuff about making a proper timestamp from three different columns, and you don't have to do anything special when the start and end times span midnight.

And, this will work intuitively no matter what timezone your users are in.